# How to compare two dates in JS? One is user selected and one is the current date

Tags: javascript, date

The user is to select a date from 3 drop down lists. Once submitting their selection, the script will compare the user's selected date and compare it to the user's current date. If the date selected by the user is greater than the current date, and error alert will appear. If the date has already occurred, then it will be displayed in a separate window.

The problem I am having is with the comparison between the two dates. I have a feeling that the problem lies with writing an incorrect path to the items to be compared.

I am a beginner. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

..........................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Date of Birth</title>

<script language= "javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    function display() { 
        var d = new Date("mm/dd/yyyy");
        var currentMonth = d.getMonth();
        var currentDay = d.getDate(); 
        var currentYear = d.getFullYear();

        userMonth = Date.parse(document.getElementById("Month").value); 
        userDay = Date.parse(document.getElementById("Day").id);
        userYear = Date.parse(document.getElementById("Year").value); 

        if(userYear >= currentYear){ 
                if(userMonth === currentMonth){ 
                            if(userDay > currentDay){  
                                alert("Sorry, this date has not occurred yet. Please submit a new entry. ");
                                }
                            else {
                                DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=200,height=280') 
                                message = "<ul><li><b>Month: </b>" + document.dob.Month.value + "</li>"; 
                                message += "<li><b>Day: </b>" + document.dob.Day.value + "</li>"; 
                                message += "<li><b>Year: </b>" + document.dob.Year.value + " </li></ul>"; 
                                DispWin.document.write(message); 
                                }   
                }
                else if(userMonth > currentMonth) { 
                     alert("Sorry, this date has not occurred yet. Please submit a new entry. ");
                }  
                else { 
                    DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=200,height=280') 
                    message = "<ul><li><b>Month: </b>" + document.dob.Month.value + "</li>"; 
                    message += "<li><b>Day: </b>" + document.dob.Day.value + "</li>"; 
                    message += "<li><b>Year: </b>" + document.dob.Year.value + " </li></ul>"; 
                    DispWin.document.write(message);
                    }   
        }
        else { 
            DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=200,height=280') 
            message = "<ul><li><b>Month: </b>" + document.dob.Month.value + "</li>"; 
            message += "<li><b>Day: </b>" + document.dob.Day.value + "</li>"; 
            message += "<li><b>Year: </b>" + document.dob.Year.value + " </li></ul>"; 
            DispWin.document.write(message);

            }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<p> Please enter the date of birth of the applicant?  <br /> 
<form action="" name="dob"> 
    <select style="width: 100px" id="Month" name="Month">
      <option>Month: </option>
      <option id="0">January</option> 
      <option id="1">Febuary</option>
      <option id="2">March</option>
      <option id="3">April</option> 
      <option id="4">May</option> 
      <option id="5">June</option> 
      <option id="6">July</option> 
      <option id="7">August</option> 
      <option id="8">September</option> 
      <option id="9">October</option> 
      <option id="10">November</option> 
      <option id="11">December</option>  
    </select>

    <select style="width: 80px" id="Day" name="Day"> 
        <option>Day: </option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
    </select>

    <select style="width: 80px" id="Year" name="Year"> 
        <option>Year: </option>
        <option>Before 1980</option>
        <option>1980</option> 
        <option>1981</option>
        <option>1982</option>
        <option>1983</option>
        <option>1984</option>
        <option>1985</option>
        <option>1986</option>
        <option>1987</option>
        <option>1988</option>
        <option>1989</option>
        <option>1990</option>
        <option>1991</option>
        <option>1992</option>
        <option>1993</option>
        <option>1994</option>
        <option>1995</option>
        <option>1996</option>
        <option>1997</option>
        <option>1998</option>
        <option>1999</option>
        <option>2000</option>
        <option>2001</option>
        <option>2002</option>
        <option>2003</option>
        <option>2004</option>
        <option>2005</option>
        <option>2006</option>
        <option>2007</option>
        <option>2008</option>
        <option>2009</option>
        <option>2010</option>
        <option>2011</option>
        <option>2012</option>
        <option>2013</option>
        <option>2014</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br /> 
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="display();" /> 
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `userMonth = Date.parse(document.getElementById("Month").value);` That doesn’t make sense; try `parseInt`, and keep in mind that months from `Date` objects are zero-based.

Comment: I know the months are zero based, that's is why i put the 'id' on them hoping that would work. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: You are missing the value attr in your options

Comment: This is out of the scope of the question, but have you considered using [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?

Comment: @aug, I am avoiding pre-written code such as Datepicker, so I can build it myself for practice. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: Handling invalid dates like 31stFeb is cumbersome in custom logic.Also take care of leap years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write this logic as simple as this:

```
function display() { 
        var d = new Date();
        //clear all these values to 0 if you need to compare year,month, day only.
        d.setHours(0);
        d.setMinutes(0);
        d.setSeconds(0);
        d.setMiliseconds(0);

        //Use parseInt instead of Date.parse, remember to use var to avoid overriding the global object
        var userMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("Month").value); 
        var userDay = parseInt(document.getElementById("Day").value);
        var userYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("Year").value); 
        var selectedDate = new Date(userYear,userMonth,userDay);

        //Use getTime to compare instead of comparing manually.
        if(selectedDate.getTime() >= d.getTime()){ 
                 alert("Sorry, this date has not occurred yet. Please submit a new   entry. ");
        }
        else {          
           DispWin = window.open('', 'NewWin', 'toolbar=no,status=no,width=200,height=280') 
                                message = "<ul><li><b>Month: </b>" + document.dob.Month.value + "</li>"; 
                                message += "<li><b>Day: </b>" + document.dob.Day.value + "</li>"; 
                                message += "<li><b>Year: </b>" + document.dob.Year.value + " </li></ul>"; 
                                DispWin.document.write(message); 
                }
    }
```

And fix your html also:
Month:

```
<select style="width: 100px" id="Month" name="Month">
      <option>Month: </option>
      <option value="0">January</option> 
      <option value="1">Febuary</option>
      <option value="2">March</option>
```

Day:

```
<select style="width: 80px" id="Day" name="Day"> 
        <option>Day: </option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
```

Year:

```
<select style="width: 80px" id="Year" name="Year"> 
        <option>Year: </option>
        <option>Before 1980</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option> 
        <option value="1980">1981</option>
```

Use `value` for all your dropdown list.

Comment: Why should I put "d.setHours(0)", minutes, seconds, and milliseconds; Is it so they are set to null, and do not interfere ?

Comment: No need to -1in month as both JavaScript month and the dropdown month is from 0 to 11

Comment: @Clarisse: if you don't set them to 0, the following situation occurs: `01/01/2010 10:00:00 AM > 01/01/2010 5:00:00 AM`. If you don't need to compare to hours, minutes, seconds,.. set them to 0

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 yes, you are completely right. Though I probably would have saved time just putting usermonth-1.

Comment: @KhanhTO, I edited my script with your corrections, it is not alerting correctly. This following line, would it work?

var userMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById("Month").id);

Comment: @Clarisse: you should use `document.getElementById("Month").value` and modify all your dropdowns to use value also. Check my updated answer

Comment: @KhanhTO, All the values worked perfect! The program works exactly how I intended. But the month's value is being displayed from the else statement, as a number one less than its real numeral. How would I change it to display the string of the month?

Comment: @Clarisse: try `document.dob.Month.options[document.dob.Month.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: @KhanhTO, Thank you very much for all your help, and being patient!

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare Date objects directly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F49An/1)

#### JavaScript

```
var now = new Date(2013, 9, 7);
var nextYear = new Date(2014, 1, 1);

console.log (now > nextYear); // false
console.log (now < nextYear); // true
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution to just getting an accurate greater or lesser conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you already parse out year, month, and date from your inputs. Year/month/date are integers.
You can simply do:

```
var now = new Date();
var inputDate = new Date(Date.parse(year+'-'+month+'-'+date)); //just make sure the parsed date is correct
```

Then you can simple compare now and inputDate